# Converting PDF to Color PCL 5 with Ghostscript

Tags: pdf, ghostscript, printer-control-language

I'm using Ghostscript 9.09 and try create PCL 5 with color, but only get a mono file. What are the correct arguments for this problem?

Passing the following arguments:

```
-q
-dQUIET
-dBATCH
-dNOPAUSE
-sDEVICE=ljet4
-sOutputFile=d:\\output.pcl
c:\\input.pdf
```

Comment: The "djet500c" device is create PCL5 code with color, but printed forms is not good. When printed out normally empty rows are filled whit black.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper device is cljet5c. This is dev device so need set in psi\msvc.mak cljet5c.dev and rebuild that.